# How Can I Add Separate Unique Body Class To Pages on Blogger Blog

Tags: html, css, xml, blogger, blogspot

I want to automatically add unique class names for Homepage and Post page to the `<body>` tag.

Example:

Show `<body class='post-page'>` on post page and

Show `<body class='homepage-page'>`on homepage

Comment: If you want to dynamically add a class to body tag, you can pick the page name from url and add the same in body tag using Javascript or any other scripting language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `b:class` operator for achieving this. It works by adding classes to the parent element. The code will look like -

```
<body>
   <b:class cond='data:view.isPost' name='post-page'/>
   <b:class cond='data:view.isHomepage' name='homepage-page'/>
```

Comment: Wow!!  Perfect answer, Thanks @prayag Verma , it worked perfectly. You just saved my day man. Tganks